# Module was built without debug information

Tags: c#, msbuild, finalbuilder

Error when attaching debugger to process:

> "To debug this module change the project build configuration to debug
>   mode."

I'm running finalbuilder using MSBUILD.  The output says:

> Running C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe with
>   parameters : /t:Build /nr:false /logger:FinalBuilderLogger,"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\FinalBuilder 7\FinalBuilder.MSBuild.Logging.v4.0.dll"
>   /noconlog /p:Configuration="Debug";Platform="AnyCPU" /v:normal /m
>   /p:solutionDir="C:\TFS10\Ecc\TestBranch\" "ProjectName.csproj"

Unless I missed something (wouldn't be the first time), these parameters suggest a Debug build with no optimizations.  So why the error?

Note: I have experienced a strange issue when doing my builds in finalbuilder where I have to set an output path in the first property group in msbuild:

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration> 
 <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
 <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>/* this has to be here */
```

In this group `<DebugType>` and `<DebugSymbols>` are **not** set.  So they are defaults.

If it's set in the next property group, `'Debug|AnyCPU'` property group alone I get a build error regarding output path not found:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
```

This suggests that the build condition is the default (blank) rather than Debug for some reason.

Comment: look at the "Build" tab in your project properties. Maybe "Optimize code" is checked

Comment: When the Configuration is set to Debug, the option to optimize is off.  In release/all configurations it is on.

Comment: are you using an external builder or visual studio?. I'm talking about visualstudio project properties

Comment: look for <Optimize>true</Optimize>

Comment: I set Optimize to false in release and added Optimize = false to the first configuration and it still gives me this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FinalBuilder was not copying the PDB file. In my case the server already had PDB files, but they didn't match the current build.  So with the error the issue was hard to track down.  Wish they said "can't find the PDB file" instead of the vague optimizations are off...